# TTTAttributedLabel "Read More >" tail truncation with several attributes possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring, tttattributedlabel

[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) support a custom truncation string via `truncationTokenString` as well as `truncationTokenStringAttributes`.

However, I am wanting to go a bit further and set several string attributes on the truncation string, including different fonts and colours. This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Truncated String]

The arrow at the end can be achieved using a font icon, so I was thinking of the following string:

`@"… Read More >"`

`'HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS' (U+2026)` + `Read More` + `> character from a font`.

Unfortunately [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) doesn't allow me to set the ranges for various attributes.

Does anyone have a good solution for this or will have have to do it manually and basically calculate the string as it can be drawn on two lines including the `@"… Read More >"` string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just answering my own question in case anyone stumbled onto it needing the same functionality.

At the time of posting the question `TTTAttributedLabel` only supported setting attributes on the whole truncation token string.

I added functionality for NSAttributedString support (for which you can specify ranges, which was missing from the plan NSDictionary with attributes approach) and submitted a pull request. It hasn't yet been merged into the main branch for `TTTAttributedLabel`, but in case anyone's in need of the same functionality you can find the PR here:

https://github.com/runmad/TTTAttributedLabel/commit/628de3f9cb688eb58fffdbb6e7ff81fa0d8b7f4a

Comment: Hi @runmad can you please tell me how can i get tap event on this truncation String??

Comment: @BhavikKama currently you cannot add a link to it - unless you fork the repo and add it yourself.