# How to make truncationTokenString of TTTAttributedLabel a link?

Tags: ios, url, truncation, tttattributedlabel

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a TTTAttributedLabel (https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) for iOS 6.1. I am using the truncationtokenstring property of the TTTAttributedLabel to format the ending (by default an ellipsis ...), when text is too long and truncated to be: "...Read More >".

I can format this truncationtokenstring by changing its foreground color etc. like in this post:
[TTTAttributedLabel "Read More >" tail truncation with several attributes possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272829/tttattributedlabel-read-more-tail-truncation-with-several-attributes-possibl)

But how do I make the truncationtokenstring a link, so that when the user clicks on "...Read More >" I can invoke the delegate and display more information?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to figure this out myself but it didn't seem possible with the current version, so made my own fork and implemented this (may not be the best code but it works).

https://github.com/renssies/TTTAttributedLabel

The way it works is simple, just add a NSLinkAttributeName to truncationTokenStringAttributes. This is iOS 7+ only of course.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I give link to that truncationTokenString?

Answer (score -1):

I have created a subclass of UILabel called [ResponsiveLabel](https://github.com/hsusmita/ResponsiveLabel/).You can add style to custom truncation token as well as specify action on tap.

```
NSString *expansionToken = @"Read More ...";
NSString *str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:kExpansionToken attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor],NSFontAttributeName:self.customLabel.font}];
[self.customLabel setAttributedTruncationToken:attribString withAction:^(NSString *tappedString) {
  NSLog(@"Tap on truncation text");
}];
[self.customLabel setText:str withTruncation:YES];
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.